# Blender 2.73a Linux mipmap disable is not working

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

I want the viewport to filter the texture as closest and from what I read to do so I need to disable mipmaps. I'm using Linux Mint Cinnamon 64 bit Laptop with HD4000 graphics and in Blender 2.73a in Preferences-System the mipmap disable is not working. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

EDIT

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Works for me.. Is it possible you could add a screenshot of what you are doing and what is happening?

Comment: Screenshot added, I should also note that I'm using cycles